# How to add bulk user list to telegram channel

Tags: .net, selenium, telegram

i have a telegram users list by username any way to add them to my channel by automation ?

Can i do this by telegram API or just writing small program with selenium web drive ?

Comment: use telethon, but i guess now telegram is strict in bot detection so you might be out of luck now.